# Is there a way to get keyboard events without JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, keyboard-events, event-listener

I want to get my program to unhide main window when user presses some shortcut. Is there a way to get the global key events, not only the ones which happened when focus was inside application frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might do what you want.  Note that this code is checking for a Ctr-F keystroke.  I use this code to open up a find dialog from anything in the application.  I'm pretty sure that the app has to have focus though.  Something to try at least...

```
AWTEventListener listener = new AWTEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
    try {
      KeyEvent evt = (KeyEvent)event;
      if(evt.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED && evt.getModifiers() == KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK && evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F) {

      }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
};

            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(listener, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
```

EDIT: I think I understand what you want.  Basically when the app does NOT have focus.  If so then you'll probably have to hook into the OS events with a native API (JNI) but that forces you to a specific OS...

Comment: Sad. I hoped there will be some platform-independent way :(

Comment: Make sure to check the link that altanis provided below.  That has a little discussion about (possibly) why it is not in Java.  Something about maybe OSX does not have that.  I have not done enough OSX programming to know if that is true or false though...

Comment: This is what I call "slipshod" answer. This code is **useless** as it is. You must implement it with the appropriate import(s) and use of this kbd listener! In short, a fully workable code! Moreover, I don't think that it workds w/o using a Jframe or other kind of frame. This is definitely a "downvote" case, however, I never do it. I prefer commenting on it.

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458756/java-system-wide-keyboard-shortcut) might be useful. I'm not sure if there is one library that will work for Windows/Linux/Mac. For Windows you will need some external library that uses native code to create a keyboard hook. I have no idea how to do it on the other OSes.

Answer (score -3):

A solution to do this by using a JFrame is to set his opacity to 0.0 and to add the Keylistener to it. But the user will see an icon in his shortcut bar...

Comment: This method will not allow the user to interact with windows behind the JFrame. And the JFrame would still have to be in focus.