# global hotkeys in Java

Tags: java, native, jna, hotkeys

I'm trying to make an app that uses global hotkeys, and I've been stuck in it for about 2 days trying to figure it out, before deciding to use jintellitype api. I always get a problem when I run the example provided on [Jintellitype's website](http://melloware.com/products/jintellitype/index.html) :  Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform, I use a 64-bit JRE, 64 bit windows, and couldn't find a solution for it : neither on the site/forums nor using google.

I'm not familiar with dealing with .dll files and JNI/JNA, but I think that to get things working I should generate a .dll file and add it to system folder, or just get a pre-made .dll file like the one provided by Jintellitype (please correct me if I was wrong).

So, what is the main idea behind using JIntellitype? How could I solve the problem I'm facing?

Comment: I've solved this using JNA to write a keyboard hook, or more easily (for me anyway) tying in Java with AutoIt v3.

Comment: for JNA I gave it a look but couldn't glue things up , any tutorial for writing keyboard hooks for beginners ?

Comment: Not that I know of, but there's plenty out there on how to do this in C/C++, so you'll need to borrow those ideas.

Comment: Have a look here though: [jna-keyboard-hook-in-windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078646/jna-keyboard-hook-in-windows).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels could you please write your comment in a separate answer to mark it as an accepted solution ?

Comment: I'm not sure that an answer that is nothing more than a link constitutes an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your problem was and made you look into jintellitype, but have you checked this post: [Is there a way to get keyboard events without JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609068/is-there-a-way-to-get-keyboard-events-without-jframe)