# Custom keyboard shortcut in java

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, acceleratorkey

I am developing a java swing application. I want to add a keyboard shortcut say <kbd>CTRL</kbd>    + <kbd>H</kbd>. This should perform the same action performed by jButton1 when clicked.

This shortcut should behave in the same way even when jButton1 is not focused.

I tried with KeyEventDispatcher, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. Is there any other way?

Comment: Dynamically generating Swing Components? We can add shortcuts to a component but not application wide - `component.getInputMap().put(aKeyStroke, aCommand);`

Answer (score 3):

Ok -  First I don't think there is a way to set application wide shortcuts in Java Swing(Refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458756/java-system-wide-keyboard-shortcut)). But for a component it is possible.

You have to use a create an `Action` for the `KeyStroke`. But for Windows I found this library very [helpful](http://code.google.com/p/jintellitype/).

```
    {
        KeyStroke cancelKeyStroke = KeyStroke
                .getKeyStroke((char) KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
        Keymap map = JTextComponent.getKeymap(JTextComponent.DEFAULT_KEYMAP);
        map.addActionForKeyStroke(cancelKeyStroke, cancelKeyAction);
    }
    private static Action cancelKeyAction = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            Component comp = (Component) ae.getSource();
            Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(comp);
            if (window instanceof Dialog) {
                window.dispose();
            } else if (comp instanceof JTextComponent
                    && !(comp instanceof JFormattedTextField)) {
                JTextComponent tc = (JTextComponent) comp;
                int end = tc.getSelectionEnd();
                if (tc.getSelectionStart() != end) {
                    tc.setCaretPosition(end);
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question can be found here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#registerKeyboardAction%28java.awt.event.ActionListener,%20java.lang.String,%20javax.swing.KeyStroke,%20int%29

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), using classes [`KeyStroke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html) and [`InputMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputMap.html). From Oracle's [`TextComponentDemo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TextComponentDemoProject/src/components/TextComponentDemo.java) (slightly modified, but still using [DefaultEditorKit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultEditorKit.html#backwardAction) as example):

```
// CTRL + H
KeyStroke key = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_H, Event.CTRL_MASK);
// bind the keystroke to an object
inputMap.put(key, DefaultEditorKit.backwardAction);
```

Use them over [Key Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) when you want the event fired even when the component doesn't have the focus:

> [Key listeners are also difficult if the key binding is to be active when the component doesn't have focus.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the <kbd>Control</kbd> key explicitly as a modifier, use the `MASK` returned by `getMenuShortcutKeyMask()` for a better cross-platform user experience. `ImageApp`is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513).